[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 - Client unable to establish connection
I am trying to run odoo project
ubuntu: 22.04
pyodbc==4.0.28
python: 3.8
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022

**ERROR: DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
             DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection**

isql -v -k - With this command i connect to my the server and there is no problem  

input > openssl version
output > OpenSSL 1.1.1p  21 Jun 2022

but

input > sudo apt list --installed | grep openssl
output > libxmlsec1-openssl/jammy,now 1.2.33-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
         openssl/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17 amd64 [installed]


I changed openssl.cnf file and add some new lines (from other solution that did not work)
**openssl_conf = default_conf
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1**

Also Tried CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
